# char conversion in bitwise operations

Tags: c, casting, bitwise-operators

I'm implementing a function that will print out a bitmask. I would like to do this on byte at a time. I've come across a strange type conversion problem I can't make sense of.

The following code snippet prints 256

```
char i = 128;
int j = 256;
printf("%u", (i & j));
```

Whereas Changing i to int returns 0:

```
int i = 128;
int j = 256;
printf("%d", (i & j));
```

What accounts for the strange behaviour of the first?

Comment: Passing an `int` where an `unsigned` is expected is a bad idea. Always pass the correct types for the format string.

Comment: With `char i = 128;`, what value do you expect to be stored in `i`?  128, -128, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `char` is signed on your system. That is why 128 gets [sign-extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) on conversion to `int` when you perform `(i & j)`

Therefore, 128 becomes `0xFFFFFF80`, so `&` is performed on `0x00000100` and `0xFFFFFF80`:

```
00000000000000000000000100000000 // 256
11111111111111111111111110000000 // 128, sign-extended
```

When you perform the same operation on `int`, no sign extension is performed, so you get zero as expected.

To avoid this behavior, specify that `i` should be an `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char i = 128;
int j = 256;
printf("%u", (i & j));
```

This produces zero ([demo](http://ideone.com/uJNkE3)).

Answer (score 1):

`char i=128` is a *signed* value, and gets sign-extended to an `int` when you `&` it with `j`.